# LOAD DATA INFILE only 1 record inserted

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a csv file that I'm trying to import via the command line. But only 1 row is being inserted.
They are comma separated values. I'm on a Mac using Excel Mac. I save as a csv file. How can I tell if the lines are terminated by \r or \n or both? Here is the code I used:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/eric/Documents/contacts_test.csv' INTO TABLE `contacts_tmp` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (clientid,contactid,title,fname,mname,lname,suffixname,salutation,occupation,employer,home_addr1,home_addr2,home_city,home_state,home_zip,home_county,primary_addr1,primary_addr2,primary_city,primary_state,primary_zip,primary_county,work_addr1,work_addr2,work_city,work_state,work_zip,work_county,email,phone_home,phone_mobile,phone_work,fax,phone_other,codes);
```

thanks

Comment: Command as such doesnt have any problem. Did you check the command in Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 6):

Had the same issue, `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'` did the job.

Answer (score 5):

I would just recommend trying the same command with ... LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ... and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Mac text files are generally ended with '\n' nowadays.  An older class app might still use '\r' but that's pretty rare these days.

Comment: its not working i used this content in csv https://sodocumentation.net/mysql/topic/2356/load-data-infile

Answer (score 3):

If in your file the line is terminated by the `,`, then you should add `LINES TERMINATED BY ',\r\n'`.

This will solve your issue as it did with mine.

Answer (score 1):

Mac text files usually end in `\r` but you can find this out by using a hex editor and seeing what the lines end with.

Comment: '\n' is more common nowadays.  See comment above.

Comment: Thanks! Got the same problem and this one solved the problem!

Comment: I read somewhere that it was Mac OS 9 or older that uses '\r'.
Mac OS X uses '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

Just try removing `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` altogether from your query.

If you don't specify a delimiter, MySQL fill figure it out automatically.

Comment: If you specify no FIELDS or LINES clause, the defaults are the same as if you had written this:

FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY '' ---- that is what the mySQL documentation says.